# How to insert/add array of nested objects into mongodb database with nodejs and mongoose using body-parser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm trying to make a post request to insert data to mongo database. I'm using `mongoose` for this. I have created the `mongoose` `Schema` like below -

```
const countrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    country_id: {
      type : Number,
      required: true,
      unique : true
    },
    country_name : {
      type : String,
      required : true,
      unique : true
    },
    country_description : {
      type : String,
      required : true,
      unique : true
    },
    country_currency : {
      type : String,
      required : true,
      unique : true
    },
    country_capital : {
      type : String,
      required : true,
      unique : true
    },
    country_numberof_districs : {
      type : Number,
      required : true
    },
    country_createdat : {
      type : Date,
      required : true
    },
    country_districs : {
      districs : [
        {
          distric_id : {
            type : Number,
            // required : true,
          },
          distric_name : {
            type : String,
            // required : true,
          },
          distric_description : {
            type : String,
            // required : true,
          },
          distric_famous_for : {
            type : String,
            // required : true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
});
```

and below is my post method -

```
router.post('/addcountry', (request, response, next) => {
  
  const district = [];
  district.push({
    distric_id: request.body.distric_id,
    distric_name : request.body.distric_name,
    distric_description : request.body.distric_description,
    distric_famous_for : request.body.distric_famous_for
  });


  let newCountry = new country({
     country_id : request.body.country_id,
     country_name : request.body.country_name,
     country_description : request.body.country_description,
     country_currency : request.body.country_currency,
     country_capital : request.body.country_capital,
     country_numberof_districs : request.body.country_numberof_districs,
     country_createdat : new Date(),
     country_districs : {
       districs : [district]
     }
  });
  country.addCountry(newCountry, (err, country) =>{
    console.log('came here');
    if(err){
      response.json({
        success : false,
        message : 'failed to add country' + err
      });
    }else {
      response.json({
        success : true,
        message : 'country added successfully'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I tested with `Postman`. it works fine without `districs` part. I tried to post below object -

```
{
    "country_id" : 909773,
    "country_name" : "USA",
    "country_description" : "UNITED STATRE",
    "country_currency" : "USD",
    "country_capital" : "NEWYORK",
    "country_numberof_districs" : 100,
    "country_districs": {
        "districs":
        [
            {
                "distric_id": 777,
                "distric_name" : "melbourne",
                "distric_description" : "no des",
                "distric_famous_for" : "beaches"
            },
            {
                "distric_id": 900,
                "distric_name" : "sydney",
                "distric_description" : "no des",
                "distric_famous_for" : "beaches"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The result was like this -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e37b5c3c6b07153600a7f6"),
    "country_id" : 909773,
    "country_name" : "USA",
    "country_description" : "UNITED STATRE",
    "country_currency" : "USD",
    "country_capital" : "NEWYORK",
    "country_numberof_districs" : 100,
    "country_createdat" : ISODate("2017-04-04T10:54:20.726Z"),
    "country_districs" : {
        "districs" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("58e37b5c3c6b07153600a7f7")
            }
        ]
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**Note** : First I tried with one district, it also didn't work. how can I add this distric object(there can be many. like distric array).and how can I iterate through all the distric objects. Hope your help with this.

Comment: Can you try this while making the country - `let newCountry = new country({
      country_districs : {
       districs : req.body.country_districts.districts
     }
  });` along with the rest of the fields...

Comment: if `districts` key is not something you surely want, you can simply store the array of objects by defining  a variable in your schema as array, and you can store you array of objects to that corresponding key.
If you want, i can post a simple example, only if districts is not a mandatory requirement for you

Comment: try changing
    country_districs : {
          districs : [district]
    }
to 
     country_districs : {
        districs : district
    }

Comment: thanx everyone, but how if there are more than one `distric`.

Comment: @JyotmanSingh, it works fine. it should be `districs : req.body.country_districts.districs`. thanks for the help. if you can put this as an answer I can accept. anyway thanks for everyone who helped. good luck and cheers!

Comment: Thank You so much, my answer in your question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this while making the country -

```
let newCountry = new country({ 
    country_districs : { 
        districs : req.body.country_districs.districs
     } 
});
```

along with the rest of the fields...